# Load 3d model in aframe-globe-component

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js, aframe

I am trying to load a gltf model in aframe-globe-component
through the below code

```
 const loaderPath='https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/scenePerson1.gltf'
globeEntity.setAttribute('globe', {
           customThreeObject: d => new THREE.Mesh(
     new THREE.GLTFLoader().load(  loaderPath  ),
     new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 'palegreen' })
    ),
    customThreeObjectUpdate: (obj, d) => {
      console.log(d.elevation* 5e-5, d.lat ,',', d.lon);
      Object.assign(obj.position, globeEntity.components.globe.getCoords(d.lat, d.lon, d.elevation* 5e-5));
    }
  });
  
 
    fetch('https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/nzpointv2.json').then(res => res.json()).then(pt => {
     globeEntity.setAttribute('globe',   {
      customLayerData: pt,
      labelsData: pt
   });
  });
```

but getting this error. Wondering how I could fix this.

```
aframe:48478 TypeError: onLoad is not a function
at aframe:48468:6
at aframe:35346:18
```

The base code is available here https://github.com/vasturiano/aframe-globe-component/tree/master/examples/custom-layer

tried this as well but no success :

```
 const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(loaderPath, function (gltf) {
  globeEntity.setAttribute('globe', {
       customThreeObject: d => new THREE.Mesh(

 new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 'palegreen' })
),
customThreeObjectUpdate: (obj, d) => {
  console.log(d.elevation* 5e-5, d.lat ,',', d.lon);
  Object.assign(obj.position, 
 globeEntity.components.globe.getCoords(d.lat, d.lon, d.elevation* 5e-5));
  }
 });
    });
```

Code is available here (line 174 to 185):
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fluttering-midnight-team?path=index.html%3A169%3A5

just click "Remix to edit" on top, so it can be edited

Same in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/MohsSpark829/dr36yahw/7/

and here as well

```js
 const globeEntity = document.getElementById("globe");
 
 
      const loaderPath =
        "https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/scenePerson1.gltf";
      const loaderPath1 =
        "https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/OEMBZ60.jpg?v=1657491909954";
     

      const getAlt = (d) => d.elevation * 5e-5;
      const catColor = d3.scaleOrdinal(
        d3.schemeCategory10.map((col) => polished.transparentize(0.2, col))
      );
      
       const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load(loaderPath, function (gltf) {
      globeEntity.setAttribute('globe', {
           customThreeObject: d => new THREE.Mesh(
    
     new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 'palegreen' })
    ),
    customThreeObjectUpdate: (obj, d) => {
      console.log(d.elevation* 5e-5, d.lat ,',', d.lon);
      Object.assign(obj.position, globeEntity.components.globe.getCoords(d.lat, d.lon, d.elevation* 5e-5));
    }
  });
        });
        
  
      

      fetch(
        "https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/nzpointv2.json?v=1658266192821"
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((pt) => {
          globeEntity.setAttribute("globe", {
            customLayerData: pt,
            labelsData: pt,
          });
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>A-Frame 3D Globe Component Example</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Example for 3D Globe component." />

    <!-- from https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-gltf.html-->
    <script src="https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/../3rdparty/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/d3"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/polished@3.5.2/dist/polished.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/aframe"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/aframe-extras/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.statically.io/gh/vasturiano/aframe-globe-component/c23c2a7e/dist/aframe-globe-component.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene >
      <a-assets>
        <img
          id="skyTexture"
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/clear-sunny-sky.jpg?v=1657244930844"
        />
        <a-asset-item
          id="Person1"
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/scenePerson1.gltf"
        ></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>

      <a-entity position="0 0 15" movement-controls="fly: true; speed: 0.5">
        <a-entity
          cursor="rayOrigin: mouse; mouseCursorStylesEnabled: true;"
          raycaster="objects: [globe]; interval: 100"
        ></a-entity>
        <a-entity
          laser-controls="hand: left"
          raycaster="objects: [globe]; interval: 100; lineColor: steelblue; lineOpacity: 0.85; "
        ></a-entity>
        <a-entity
          laser-controls="hand: right"
          raycaster="objects: [globe]; interval: 100; lineColor: steelblue; lineOpacity: 0.85;"
        ></a-entity>

        <a-camera
          look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: false"
          wasd-controls="enabled: false"
        >
          <a-text
            id="globe-tooltip"
            position="0 -0.6 -1"
            width="2"
            align="center"
            color="lavender"
          ></a-text>
          <a-text
            id="globe-tooltip-details"
            position="0 -0.7 -1"
            width="1"
            align="center"
            color="lavender"
          ></a-text>
        </a-camera>
      </a-entity>
      <a-sky color="#001"></a-sky>

      <a-entity
        id="globe"
        scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"
        globe="
        globe-image-url: //unpkg.com/three-globe/example/img/earth-day.jpg;
     
      "
        rotation="45 -180 0"
      ></a-entity>
    </a-scene>

    <a-entity
      gltf-model="#Person1"
      scale="1 2 1"
      animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: true; dur: 1000"
    >
    </a-entity>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to provide a load callback function for THREE.GLTFLoader().load(  loaderPath  ), change it to HREE.GLTFLoader().load(  loaderPath, function(){ console.log("processmydata") //do what you want to do on Load}  ) .........Refer this-https://threejs.org/docs/?q=GLT#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader

Comment: thanks @BKalra, I updated the question based on your advise, still not getting it, could you please comment

Comment: Can you share the code on a fiddle or somewhere else

Comment: Done, both in Fiddle and in here

Comment: How can I help stakOverflowers (new word!) to help me with this questions? How can I motivate stakOverflowers  to participate in this question